# Is there any rule preventing the ghost of a slain creature from existing while its animated skeleton exists?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, undead, world-building

I'm aware I can just GM fiat it if I like, but I'm curious to know if in the rules-as-written there exists language that prevents Tom's ghost from existing at the same time as Tom's animated skeleton also exists. In the homebrew I'm running, I had the idea that Tom's ghost wants the party to slay Tom's skeleton and properly bury his remains — his unburied and animated remains being the reason the ghost formed and persists.

Comment: If that was impossible it would need to be made possible. It looks awesome!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[James Jacobs](http://paizo.com/people/JamesJacobs) (Paizo's Creative Director) says [you can create zombies from the corpses of creatures that turned into a ghost](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=1190?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#59497):

> *Can you make a new zombie/skeleton from the remains of a defeated zombie/skeleton?*
>
> **Nope**.
>
> *Can you make a ghost(or other incorperal undead) and still make a zombie or other unintelligent undead of the corpse?*
>
> **Yes**.
>
> *Can you make a ghost(or other incorperal undead) and still make a ghoul or other intellgent undead? if not will the ghost be pulled in to the body to provide the intelligents for the body or will it just not work?*
>
> **Nope**.

Which actually makes a lot of sense, ghosts are described several times as *disembodied undead* on the [Classic Horrors Revisited](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8ban?Pathfinder-Chronicles-Classic-Horrors-Revisited) campaign setting. Though no specific ruling is given about whether or not you can turn a ghost's former body into another type of (corporeal) undead creature.

Comment: Also potentially relevant is the text of the *magic jar* spell, which specifies that only sentient undead have souls.

Comment: Awesome research as always friend.